# perl Term::ANSIColor not working on Raspberry Pi Console

Tags: linux, perl, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

This code:

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
print color("blink bold red"), "TEST\n";
print color("reset");
```

Has worked for eons on whatever linux console I have used it on. However, I when I try it on a Raspberry Pi console (not Xwindows) running Raspbian Stretch it simply colors the text red but does not blink. Anyone have any ideas as to how I can get this to work?

Comment: The proper name is Linux framebuffer console, just so everyone knows what we're talking about. I can confirm that blink does not work.

Comment: Yes, it definitely does not work, hence the post. Do you happen to know why it works in a Centos console ( frame buffer ) for example and not in the Raspian console/Frame buffer. I believe that finding out and understanding the differences between the two is the first step to me finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Attributes such as blink, italic, or bold may not work with the 256-color palette. -[documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor#Supported-Colors)

Comment: Yes, I see that the documentation that you site says: "Note that not all attributes are supported by all terminal types, and some terminals may not support any of these sequences." 

But what is "supported by all terminal types" supposed to mean? How many unique linux terminals/consoles types are there? --not talking about terminal emulators. From any linux machine (not in Xwindows) I get "/bin/login --" when I type: ps -o 'cmd=' -p $(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$). To simply say "it may not work" does not account for the fact that it does work on what seem to be the same "terminal types".

Comment: I can even find instances where blink works on machines with the exact same terminfo and termcap output as that of machines where it does not work. Please see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269809/blink-codeescape-code-has-been-removed

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting I can conclude that the reason that perl ANSI color's blink feature does not work on a Raspberry PI is because the monitor is connected via HDMI. perl ANSI color does in fact blink on a Raspberry PI if one logs in remotely from a machine with a VGA monitor.

Update: Further testing concludes the blinking feature will NOT work by using a HDMI to VGA adapter to connect a VGA monitor to the raspberry PI -- so save yourself the money. The only way possible to get perl ANSIColor's blink feature to work on a PI is by sshing to the machine from a VGA displayed machine.